# plot vertex with two labels one inside and the other out side the vertex

Tags: r, igraph

I have a vertex "`id`" and vertex "`value`"

```
deg <- degree(net, mode="all")
deg
ID    151  152  162  163  175  176 2110 2117 2127 2129 2130 2131 
Value  4    3    0    3    2    2    1    0    2    0    0    0
```

I use this to plot the vertex label with value and I want both the vertex "`id`" and "`value`" to be shown in the plot (ideally, I want the  "id" inside and "`Value`" is outside the vertex).

```
plot(net, vertex.size=deg*5, vertex.label=round(deg, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get a label inside the node using the `vertex.label` parameter to `plot.igraph`. It is a bit trickier to add labels outside. At least one way to do that is by managing the layout yourself, so that you know the location of every node. Then you can just use the standard `text` function to add the outside label. Here is a simple example.

```
## generate sample graph
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(8, 0.34)

ID = letters[1:8]           ## This is the ID
deg <- degree(g, mode="all")    ## This is the value

## Now generate a layout for the vertices so that we 
## can refer to the absolute position of the nodes
LO = layout_nicely(g)
LO[,1] = (LO[,1] - min(LO[,1])) / (max(LO[,1]) - min(LO[,1]))
LO[,2] = (LO[,2] - min(LO[,2])) / (max(LO[,2]) - min(LO[,2]))
LO = 2*LO - 1

## Plot and add the extra labels
plot(g, layout=LO, rescale=F, vertex.label=ID)
text(LO, labels=deg, pos=1, offset=1.5)
```

[image: Graph with labels in and out]